# Newman htmlextra reporter complains about newman is missing but it's installed

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm, postman, newman

I'm trying to install and run Postman's Newman tests collection with HTML reporter (on a jenkins podTemplate container with docker image from Postman's account) but it keeps failing because no suitable Newman version is found:

```
"npm WARN newman-reporter-htmlextra@1.19.6 requires a peer of newman@>=4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself"
```

Newman image docker is "postman/newman:5.2-alpine".

And the Run command is

```
sh "newman run tests/collection.json -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export var/reports/newman/html/index.html";
```

I've also tried to install with (the "sh" prefix is because it's in groovy script..in Jenkins) :

```
sh "npm install -g newman@4.6.1"
sh "npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra"
```

and then executing the same run command as above.

```
sh "newman run tests/collection.json -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export var/reports/newman/html/index.html";
```

But the results are the same.

What's weird is that right after I get the error mentioned above - the jenkinsfile executes the "newman run" command and successfully creates the tests report file:

```
Using htmlextra version 1.19.6
Created the htmlextra report in this location: var/reports/newman/html/index.html
```

But then exits the script/job with FAILURE.

What am I missing?
Any advice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a npm bug, https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12905

for newman-reporter-htmlextra , newman is a peer dependency.

In npm peer dependency is not detected for global packages if the dependency and the package are not installed together

In this case you can fix it by installing it together using

```
npm install -g newman newman-reporter-htmlextra
```

Try :

```
podTemplate(label: "newmanPodHtmlExtra", containers: [
containerTemplate(name: "newman", image: "dannydainton/htmlextra", command: "cat", ttyEnabled: true),
]) {
node("newmanPodHtmlExtra") {
def testsFolder = "./tests";
container("newman") {

stage("Checkout") {
checkout scm;
      }

try{
stage("Install & run Newman") {
sh "npm install -g newman newman-reporter-htmlextra";
sh "newman run ${testsFolder}/collection.json -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export var/reports/newman/html/index.html";
  }
}catch(e){}finally{

stage("Show tests results") {
publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, keepAll: false, reportDir: 'var/reports/newman/html', reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'API Tests', reportTitles: ''
    ])
  }
}


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks PDHide!
It did resolve the WARN about that reporter that doesn't find suitable Newman version, 
but still - the job exits with code 1 right after it produces the report:

'Created the htmlextra report in this location: var/reports/newman/html/index.html'.

What could be the reason for it?

Comment: @EladTalby are you sure no test failed in postman run. If test fail you get ext 1

Comment: Warn should not fail builds , are you using jenkins free style job ?

Comment: I'm using Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline job.
If one of the newman API tests fails - shouldn't it at least display the produced HTML file with the tests results, to show it has failed?    

BTW I'm using PublishHTML plugin in order to show the results file (just as described in Postman's instructions:
publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, keepAll: false, reportDir: 'var/reports/newman/html', reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'API Tests', reportTitles: ''])

Comment: Is it added as post build action what error you are getting ?

Comment: It's not a post-build action. The whole job consists of one-stage jenkinsFile/pipeline..
The stage spins-up a container with docker image of newman version 5.2 (I've tried a few versions, same result) and then runs the newman command, produces the HTML file and then the job exits with code 1.
 There's no specific error, just "ERROR: script returned exit code 1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226282/discussion-between-elad-talby-and-pdhide).

Comment: Are you using declarative pipeline ?

Comment: Scripted.
Eventually gave up on using Reporters. I'm just running Newman and it prints the results to the console.
Thanks!

Comment: @EladTalby could you try the updated groovy script and give it a try if you like